# Apache - Zeppelin using variables across paragraphs

Tags: sql, data-analysis, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to accomplish the following use case on Apache Zeppelin: 
When I write an `sql` query, for example

```
%sql SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 = ${column1=1,1|2|3|4}
```

I get a combo box displayed with these values `(1,2,3,4)` as options.
What I want to do is populate this list with all distinct values available for this column (or as a matter of fact any other set of values which I might want to take from another paragraph in form of a variable). So currently I am stuck at how to use some variables defined in one paragraph inside an `sql` statement in another paragraph ?

Diving into the code, I saw that inside the Zeppelin-interpreter, a file called `Input.java` checks for a pattern `${someColumn=someValues}`, fills up the combo-box options and then creates a simple query, and hence I have dropped the idea of populating it by running a query in the same paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ZeppelinContext](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/spark.html#zeppelincontext) to accomplish this, as it enables you to use put() and get() to set and retrieve objects between paragraphs.

Quoting the example from the linked page, note that the ***z*** object is the default instance of ZeppelinContext:

```
// Put object from scala
%spark
val myObject = ...
z.put("objName", myObject)

# Get object from python
%spark.pyspark
myObject = z.get("objName")
```

Comment: 'IPySparkZeppelinContext' object has no attribute 'put' or 'get' .. Any idea on this?

Comment: In Scala I had to add `.asInstanceOf[MyClass]`, on the contrary `get` returns an Object.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using a `Scala` variable from one paragraph to `Shell Script` in another paragraph. Here's the answer.

**In Scala Cell**

```
%spark2
val myVal = "test-value-across-paragraphs"
z.put("objName", myVal)
```

**In Shell Cell**

```
%sh
echo {objName}
```

This requires object interpolation to be enabled which can be done by setting the value of the property `zeppelin.shell.interpolation` to `true`. Check [Apache Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.1/interpreter/shell.html) for further help.

**Update May 19, 2019**

The above procedure may not work in `Zeppelin 2.2` but obviously works in `Zeppelin 2.3`. Also in `2.3`, the value of interpolation can be changed from the `sh.config` cell.

```
%sh.conf
zeppelin.shell.interpolation true
```

Comment: How to set object in shell and use in spark? Consider your example in reverse?

Comment: Not aware of the exact method but you can try setting up an `ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE` in shell and then access it in spark. For example, `%sh export MYVAR=test` and then in spark `%spark System.getenv("MYVAR")` or `%spark sys.env("MYVAR")`.